# algorithm, decrement and increment [-100, 100]

Tags: increment, decrement

I'm trying to create a cycle and decrement, increment an int.

```
int val = 0;

while(true){
   if(val < -100) val += 1;
   else val -= 1;

   myFunction(val);
}
```

It's an infinite cycle, I know but I need to send a value to myFunction between (-100, 100);

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick I think...

```
int val = 0;
int increment = 1;

while(true){
   val += increment;

   if(val < -100){
     increment = 1;
   }
   else if(val > 100){
     increment = -1;
   }

   myFunction(val);
}
```

It starts in 0 and incrementing untill reaching 100... then starts decrementing untill reaching -100... when it starts incrementing again.

If you need to start from 0 and decrementing, just change initial value of increment variable to -1 instead of 1. The same for initial value... set it as you want between -100 and 100.

Comment: It's not working, val it's having 1 always, because the condition fails: 1 < -100 ? 1 > 100 ?

Comment: If both conditions fail, it should leave `increment` unchanged, so it should keep going in the same direction.

Comment: If you test just my code it works for you? If your code adds/changes  things, may be the added/changed code is what messes the value of "val"?